# Innershadow and alternating cell color

Tags: html, css

This is my goal

[image]

How do I accomplish this using html/css and the following code fundament?

```
  <div class="classname">                      
    <table>                              
      <tbody>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td></td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td>                  
            </td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td></td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td></td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td></td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td></td>                                      
        </tr>                                      
        <tr>                            <td></td>                           <td>                             
      </tbody>                         
    </table>                                                                                                                             
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]**css**

set background color on the table cell.

```
table {

    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 7px -5px #777 inset,-7px 0px 7px -5px #777 inset;

}

table tr td {

    background:#fff;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;

}
```

**html**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Month</td>
    <td>Year</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tr:nth-child(even) td:last-child{
    background-color:#ccc;
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K7WvP/2/ still doesn't work. Can you just recreate my example?

Comment: first index background color and 2nd index box shadow see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/swPPp/)

Answer (score 4):

**CSS**

```
 tr:nth-child(even) td:last-child{
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:80%
}
table{
 -moz-box-shadow:
        inset 5px 0 5px -2px #ccc,
        inset -5px 0 5px -2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        inset 5px 0 5px -2px #ccc,
        inset -5px 0 5px -2px #ccc;
    box-shadow:
        inset 5px 0 5px -2px #ccc,
        inset -5px 0 5px -2px #ccc;
}
td{
    border-bottom:#ccc solid 1px;
    border-right:#ccc solid 1px;
    height:30px
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K7WvP/2/)**

Comment: great i also need this. coz I only did it thru php

Comment: doesn't look like that in opera.

Comment: @PeterFren it does. I checked in opera as well